# How to lock the camera in Google Maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, screen-lock

I'm trying to lock the camera so that the users can't move the map. Is there any method available for that? I tried to find it, but untill now I haven't found it yet. I also tried to find any related question for this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use

`mapFragment.getMap().getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);`

to forbid map scrolling.

You can also use `setAllGesturesEnabled(false);` (there are also rotate and tilt gestures...) For more methods see docs: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings